django - reverse for with keyword arguments not found
I am creating a web application where users can leave reviews for my company. Upon leaving a review, an email is sent to me with the review data and a link for me to easily click to approve the review to be shown on the page for all users. To do this, I used uuid to create a token for each review created. I know that the token is being passed to my review_email.html template because i can send the token as html text within the email, but for some reason i keep getting this error with the url tag:
Reverse for 'approve_review' with keyword arguments '{'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['reviews/approve/(?P[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})\Z']
EDIT: The error is coming from url tag in review_email.html
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Review
from .forms import ReviewForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import os
import uuid
# Create your views here.

def submit_review(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.token = uuid.uuid4()
            review.save()
            print(review.token)
            send_review_email(review)
            return render(request, 'reviews/thank_you.html')
        
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()
    return render(request, 'reviews/submit_review.html', {'form': form})

def send_review_email(review):
    send_mail('New Review Submitted', 'A new review has been submitted.', os.getenv('EMAIL_HOST_USER'),
            ['testemail123@hotmail.com'],
            html_message=render_to_string('reviews/review_email.html', context = {
                'name': review.name,
                'street': review.street,
                'city': review.city,
                'state': review.state,
                'zip_code': review.zip_code,
                'phone_number': review.phone_number,
                'review_text': review.review_text,
                'token': review.token
            }))

def approve_review(request, token):
    review = get_object_or_404(Review, token=token)
    review.approved = True
    review.save()
    return redirect('reviews:review_list')

review_email.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Review Submitted</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>New Review Submitted</h1>
    <p><strong>Name</strong> {{ name }}</p>
    <p><strong>Street:</strong> {{ street }}</p>
    <p><strong>City:</strong> {{ city }}</p>
    <p><strong>State:</strong> {{ state }}</p>
    <p><strong>ZIP Code:</strong> {{ zip_code }}</p>
    <p><strong>Phone Number:</strong> {{ phone_number }}</p>
    <p><strong>Review Text:</strong> {{ review_text }}</p>
    <p><strong>Token:</strong> {{ token }}</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'reviews:approve_review' token=review.token %}"></a></p>
    
</body>
</html>

models.py:
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import uuid

# Create your models here.

class Review(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='NY')
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, verbose_name='Zip Code')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, verbose_name='Phone Number')
    review_text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Review')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    token = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import approve_review

app_name = 'reviews'

urlpatterns = [
    path('submit/', views.submit_review, name='submit_review'),
    path('thanks/', views.thank_you, name='review_thanks'),
    path('', views.review_list, name='review_list'),
    path('approve/<uuid:token>', views.approve_review, name='approve_review'),
]

I am going insane trying to figure out why this isnt working, please help :)
I've tried changing directories of the review_email, changing how the context is passed from view to html render message, etc.

You don't pass in review to your view context that renders the template with the error def send_review_email(review) just token so your call renders nothing, specifically here: 'token': review.token. In your template simply use {{ token }} and all should work as expected. {{ review.token }} will only work if you pass review into the context...I can provide an answer if needed, but that should get you on track. Please let me know

delete the review.token = uuid.uuid4() in your view and set primary_key=True for token.
